# como hago esto?

Tags: mysql

me pide obtener todos los datos de dos registros de la tabla

mi sintaxis fue asi,

```
mysql> 
select
  Clave_articulo, nombre, precio, Clave_fabricante
from articulos
where nombre = 'Mouse','Teclado';
```

pero me marca error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: listo, me vas ha ayudar?

Comment: Sabías que en SQL puedes usar el operador lógico `OR`? Por ejemplo: `WHERE nombre = 'teclado' OR nombre = 'mouse'`.

Comment: nop no sabia, por que estoy estudiando programacion

Comment: Mejora la forma de preguntar. No añadas imágenes, añade el código encerrado en backticks. Estamos para ayudar, no para servir.

Comment: Recomendaciones para generar buenas preguntas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE nombre = 'Mouse','Teclado'
```

es incorrecto, intenta con

```
WHERE nombre IN ('Mouse','Teclado')
```

con este where estás buscando por condición los dos productos, con el operador "IN".